# In what scenario we have to use extension method as AsEnumerable() and ToList() in linq Query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

here we are using AsEnumerable() extension method.

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = grdLookupPracticeMultiple.GridView.GetSelectedFieldValues("ID").Select(s => (string)s).AsEnumerable();
```

and what mean `(string)s`

Answer (score 3):

The `(string)s` in this context is simply saying "cast the variable `s` as type `string`" - I'm guessing that `GetSelectedFieldValues("ID")` returns `object`, and you want a sequence of `string`s. There's actually a `.Cast<string>()` that would have done that for you.

As for when you need `AsEnumerable()` - pretty rarely, actually - and probably not in this case. The key scenario is when it *wouldn't* be otherwise. Perhaps you explicitly want to treat `IQueryable<T>` as `IEnumerable<T>` (to force LINQ-to-Objects instead of query composition). Or maybe you're dealing with something like `DataSet` where the `.Rows` etc *aren't* actually `IEnumerable<T>` for any `T`, and need help.

As for when to use `.ToList()`: when you want to create a snapshot of the data. At the moment, `strings` is a deferred execution sequence over the data. It will execute *when you `foreach` over it*. So: if the list changes between now and then : you'll get the updated contents. Often, you want the data *as it exists now*.

edit: actually, in this case `GetSelectedFieldValues` *returns* a snapshot, so: it won't actually update **in this case**, but in many others : it might; so: it needs to be considered.

So: summing up, you probably just want:

```
var strings = grdLookupPracticeMultiple.GridView.GetSelectedFieldValues("ID")
                      .Cast<string>().ToList();
```

However, if this is the dev express grid, you already get a `List<T>` from `GetSelectedFieldValues`, so maybe this would be more efficient:

```
var strings = grdLookupPracticeMultiple.GridView.GetSelectedFieldValues("ID")
                      .ConvertAll(s => (string)s);
```